# Basic issue with Foreign key while trying to insert a record

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, constraints

I have linked 3 tables:

**[T_User]**

```
AUsr_ID [PK] | AUsr_LogonID | AUsr_UserDisplayName
-------------+--------------+---------------------
    417      | VI00IV       | John Doe
```

**[T_ApplicationRoles]**

```
Role_ID [PK] | Role_Name    | Role_Description
-------------+--------------+--------------------------
    6        | Default Role | Default Role Attributed
```

**[T_ApplicationRolesUsers]**

```
RoUs_ID [PK auto-incremented] | RoUs_Role_ID [FK] | RoUs_ApUs_ID [FK]
------------------------------+-------------------+------------------
          1                   |         6         |        417
```

I manually insert a row into `T_ApplicationRolesUsers` and it went well.

When I'm trying to insert the same line in C#, I get an error:

These are the values that I'm trying to insert into `T_ApplicationRolesUser`:

```
 UserRoleToAdd.RoUs_Role_ID = 417;
 UserRoleToAdd.RoUs_ApUs_ID = 6;
```

And this is the error I get:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_T_ApplicationRolesUsers_T_ApplicationRoles".
>   The conflict occurred in database "DBS", table "dbo.T_ApplicationRoles", column 'Role_ID'.

Comment: Is there any other constraint in table `T_ApplicationRolesUsers` than PK?

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to insert something for Role_ID 417 - does that role exist? from the tables you've provided it **doesn't**, if I had to hazard a guess I'd suggest you've got your 417 and your 6 the wrong way around.

Instead of:

```
 UserRoleToAdd.RoUs_Role_ID = 417;
 UserRoleToAdd.RoUs_ApUs_ID = 6;
```

I think you meant to have:

```
 UserRoleToAdd.RoUs_Role_ID = 6;
 UserRoleToAdd.RoUs_ApUs_ID = 417;
```

Comment: I spent to many hours in the code without break. I was so absent minded! Thanks a lot motosubatsu. It was so simple :-) Cheers

Comment: @Zapfool easily enough done - we've all been there! If this sorted it for you remember to accept the answer :)